# Solving the system $3a=(b+c+d)^3$, $3b=(c+d+e)^3$, ..., $3e=(a+b+c)^3$ for real $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, contest-math

$$\begin{align}
3a&=(b+c+d)^3 \\
3b&=(c+d+e)^3 \\
3c&=(d+e+a)^3 \\
3d&=(e+a+b)^3 \\
3e&=(a+b+c)^3
\end{align}$$

I tried to use inequality for
$((\sum \alpha)/n)^r\leq \sum \alpha^r/n$ by taking $\alpha=a_1+a_2+a_3$ where $a_1,a_2,a_3\in \{a,b,c,d,e\}$.

Comment: Why don't you put `$` around all formulas?

Comment: Are variables positive?

Comment: they belong to real.

Comment: $a=b=b=c=d=e=1/3$ is one solution (but I'm not sure how much that helps).

Comment: true that..i want to show that these are the only one..

Comment: I thought there was no solution in positives since $$
\begin{cases}
3a=(b+c+d)^3 \\
3b=(c+d+e)^3 \\
3c=(d+e+a)^3 \\ 
3d=(e+a+b)^3 \\ 
3e=(a+b+c)^3 \\
\end{cases} \implies 
\begin{cases}
9bcd \le a \\
9cde \le b \\
9dea \le c \\ 
9eab \le d \\ 
9abc \le e \\
\end{cases} \implies
9^5(abcde)^3 \le (abcde) \implies 9^5(abcde)^2 \le 0
$$

Comment: got it..thank you..

Comment: @VIVID, shouldn't that end with $\le1$ instead of $\le0$? (I.e., aren't you just dividing by $(abcde)$?)

Comment: @JishuDas, all $0$'s and all $-1/3$'s are also solutions.

Comment: @BarryCipra Oh, that was a childish mistake! xD

Comment: i have updated the description. Does that help in any way.$a+b+c+d+e\leq a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3+e^3$

Comment: @JishuDas, you update is contradicted by my first comment's solution.

Comment: sorry ..did it wrong..assumed positive

Comment: solution in AOPS https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h54905p341887

Answer (score 7):

> Thanks to @CalvinLin for pinpointing that we cannot *"assume WLOG"* that the five variables are sorted as $a \le b \le c \le d \le e$.

We can still assume that the maximum element among them is $e$ $^{(*)}$. Then, by comparing $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ variables, we observe

- $$3d = (\color{red}e + a + b)^3 \ge (a + b + \color{red}c)^3 = 3e \\ \implies d \ge e \overset*\implies \boxed{d=e} \tag{1}$$

---

- $$3a = (b + c + \color{red}d)^3 \ge (\color{red}a + b + c)^3 = 3e \\\implies a \ge e \overset*\implies \boxed{a = e} \tag{2}$$

---

- $$3a = (\color{red}b + c + d)^3  \le  (c + d + \color{red}e)^3 = 3b \\\implies b \ge a = e \overset*\implies \boxed{b = e} \tag{3}$$

---

- $$3c = (d + e + \color{red}a)^3 \ge (\color{red}c + d + e)^3 = 3b \\ \implies c \ge b \implies \boxed{c = b} \tag{4}$$

---

Finally, $(1)\land(2)\land(3)\land(4) \implies \boxed{a = b = c = d = e}$.

> Also, @AlbusDumbledore provided an equivalent [solution in AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h54905p341887)

Comment: Can we apply AM GM for negative nos?

Comment: @JishuDas See the edit :)

Comment: Have a look at the "artofproblemsolving" solution indicated by Albus Dumbledore !

Comment: @JeanMarie Oh wow, I didn't notice that comment.

Comment: I disagree that "WLOG one can assume the set is sorted in ascending order".

Comment: @CalvinLin Why can't we assume $a \le b \le c \le d \le e$?

Comment: Why can you make that assumption? We can assume that $a$ is the smallest, but why must we then have $ b \leq c \leq d$? What if the solution was $ a < b > c < d > e $? How do you "WLOG" it to get $ a < b < c < d < e$ ?

Comment: If you read the solution in AOPS, this is why they had to painstakingly work though multiple equations. You have shown that $ a = e$, and need to input that into another equation.

Comment: @CalvinLin If $a < b > c < d > e$, can't we re-sort them and apply again the same thing?

Comment: State how to re sort them. IE If the true order was $ a  <  c < b < e < d$, then the first equation is $ 3 a = (b+c+d)^3$. How do you get it into the form of $ 3A = (C+B+E)^3$?

Comment: Thank you, @CalvinLin . It was my mistake. Fixed it now.

Comment: Looks good. Note that if you did (1), (3), (2), then you can "avoid" doing (4). It makes the presentation slightly cleaner, since all that you're doing is the term-wise comparison.

Comment: @CalvinLin Edited accordingly

Answer (score 3):

Notice that for all $x,y$ we have $$x^2+xy+y^2 = {1\over 2}(x^2+(x+y)^2+y^2)\geq 0$$

Now we have:
$$3(a-b) = (b-e)\color{red}{\Big(} \underbrace{b+c+d}_x )^2+\underbrace{(b+c+d)(c+d+e)}_{xy}+( 
\underbrace{ c+d+e}_y)^2\color{red}{\Big)} $$

so $${\rm sign} (a-b) = {\rm sign} (b-e) $$ and similary for:

\begin{align} {\rm sign} (b-c) &= {\rm sign} (c-a)\;\;\;\;(2) \\
{\rm sign} (c-d) &= {\rm sign} (d-b)\;\;\;\;(3) \\
{\rm sign} (d-e) &= {\rm sign} (e-c) \;\;\;\;(4)\\
{\rm sign} (e-a) &= {\rm sign} (a-d) \;\;\;\;(5)\\
\end{align}

- If $a>b$ then $b>e$ so $a>e$ and from $(5)$ we have $d>a$ so $d>e$ and now from $(4)$ we have $e>c$ and now $d>c$ so from $(2)$ we have $b>d$ so $b>c$ and now from $(2)$ we have $c>a$. So we have $$a>b>d>e>c>a$$ A contradiction.
- If $b>a$ we again get a contradiction, so $a=b=c=d=e=:x$ and all we need is to solve $x=9x^3$...

Comment: This is stupid problem any way, I spen't so many time for it and I don't know why. Well shame on me.

Comment: nice(+1) btw   It was asked in INMO 1996.........